# Why did people look at each others hands in The Book of Eli?

Tags: movie, the-book-of-eli

In the movie *The Book of Eli*, some of the characters look at each others hands the first time they meet.  I don't recall any explanation of this behavior in the movie.  What were they doing and why?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

They looked at each other's hands to see if they were shaking.

> At one point in the story it's explained that a side effect of eating too much human meat is a shaking of the extremeties.

Comment: That didn't register with me when I saw the movie.  I guess I'll have to rent it and watch it again.

Comment: I apologize, I created a new answer without realizing you put the same explanation in the hidden field

Comment: @Brenton: That's okay.  The hidden "spoiler" text can take some getting used to.  I didn't know about it until recently.

Comment: I've been ignoring this question until recently because I hadn't seen the movie. I added an answer with medical info on this, feel free to incorporate in your answer if you wish. Post me a comment if you do and I'll delete my answer, have a good one.

Comment: I didn't even notice that in the movie. That is a really nice attention to detail that shows the effort placed in making it.

Comment: BTW I've been dying to ask a question but can't figure a way to do so without it being a spoiler to this movie.

Comment: Never mind found the answer myself...

Answer (score 52):

They were checking to see if the other persons hands were steady, or were they shaking.

Shaking hands is a symptom of [Creutzfeldt-Jakob disease](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creutzfeldt-Jakob_disease), which is a form of [Transmissible spongiform encephalopathy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmissible_spongiform_encephalopathy), it is basically a human variant of [Mad Cow Desease](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bovine_spongiform_encephalopathy).

It can be caused by a genetic trait, and is difficult to catch otherwise. You basically need to be injected with serum or an endocrine extract from someone that has the disease.

Otherwise you can pick it up from eating meat from an infected human i.e. Cannibalism. See [Kuru Disease](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuru_%28disease%29) for real world evidence of this.

Basically, if you were to chow down once on one person, you'd be very unlucky to get CJD. However the more - ahem - specimens you sample the greater the chance of contracting CJD. Multiply this by the number of specimens sampled by the specimen you're eating and the probability of contracting CJD increases.

Therefore in a society where cannibalism is common place, the chances of a getting CJD - and therefore having shaking hands - could be quite high.

So, if you tend to be of a nervous disposition or suffer from an uncontrollable tick, pray you don't end up on a post apocalyptic world where cannibalism is frowned on :)

Answer (score 3):

To make things simple in the movie after the big blast from the some food supply was very low, so some people on the verge of starvation started eating other people. When you eat a human being it is said the you get the shakes on your hands.

To be safe and not be ignorant to the fact that someone was a cannibal they checked their hands first to see if they had the shakes. When you watch the movie look out for the people with shakes, for example the old woman with tea and you will understand certain scenes more.

Answer (score 3):

I like the medical answer a lot, and it make sense not to serve cannibals. But I thought to look at a biblical meaning since the movie is very spiritual. Did some research and found this in the book of Revelations.

Revelation 13:16-17 King James Version (KJV)

> 16 And he causeth all, both small and great, rich and poor, free and bond, to receive a mark in their right hand, or in their foreheads:
>
> 17 And that no man might buy or sell, save he that had the mark, or the name of the beast, or the number of his name.